# CMake can't detect freetype although it is inatalled

Tags: cmake

[image]

I'm trying to install OGRE3D but when I build it using CMake3.2.2, I get the error that I don't have freetype although I do have freetype and it is fully upgraded (I get "libtypefree6-dev is already the newest version" when I use command `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev`).

Anyway, I googled and found that there is some issue with freetype in Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) that cmake can't detect freetype and I just installed Ubuntu last weekend for the first time so I just know how to use terminal so if someone can help please be a little thorough or please tell me the exact commands to run in the terminal to make CMake detect it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30712/discussion-on-question-by-zargham-cmake-cant-detect-freetype-although-it-is-ina).